# removeObjectFromSuperView not working with if statement

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, model-view-controller, ios7

I have a button that when pressed is supposed to hide the status bar and place text in its spot. Then, when the button is pressed the label is supposed o be removed from the `view` and the status bar will re-appear. The first part works -- the status bar is hidden and the label is placed on the `view`, the problem is when I press the button a second time (to remove the text and put back the status bar). The status bar re-appears but the label is not being removed from the `view`. To achieve this I am using an if statement. I am also using removeObjectFromSuperView which is the thing that is not working.

Here is the code:

```
 - (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {

UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 21)];

label.text = @"This is a test";

[label setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:13]];

label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;



if (hidden == NO) {

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarHidden = YES;

    [self.view addSubview:label];

    hidden = YES;

}else if (hidden == YES) {

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarHidden = NO;



    [label removeFromSuperview];

    hidden = NO;

}

}
```

Thanks
**Edit: Here is what the problem looks like:**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to track your label outside of the `buttonPressed:` method. Right now you are creating a new label every time the button is pressed then removing that same label.

So for example:

```
@interface MyViewController () {
    UILabel *label;
}

- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
    if (hidden == NO) {

        [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarHidden = YES;

        label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 21)];
        label.text = @"This is a test";
        [label setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:13]];
        label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

        [self.view addSubview:label];

        hidden = YES;

    } else if (hidden == YES) {

        [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarHidden = NO;

        [label removeFromSuperview];
        label = nil;

        hidden = NO;
    }
}
```

You can also set `label = nil;` once you remove it from the super view.

Comment: I just did what you said and I still have the same problem, thanks.

Comment: @user3186310 I expanded the `buttonPressed:` method. Try that.